# Is it possible to install Android Gingerbread on a Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: rom-flashing, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, custom-roms, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I have an old Samsung Galaxy Nexus from years ago and I was wondering whether it's possible to flash an older Android version like Gingerbread on it using a custom ROM. Since it was originally launched with ICS, I'm not sure if there are any Gingerbread ROMs for it and whether it's even capable of running Gingerbread.

Comment: I vaguely remember seeing a render showing a GNex on GB, but I reckon that was made way before its release. The only example of running a lower Android version than stock that I know is Nexus 4 (4.2) running a ROM ported from Optimus G (4.1) due to their hardware similarities, and it was buggy as hell. Generally it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for the info @AndyYan